# Videojs Caption not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, video.js

Unable to produce captions in firefox using coldfusion language.But it is worKing fine in google chrome.

```
  <cfset newElement = ''>
  <cfset newElement=newElement & 'WEBVTT' & chr(10)>     
   <cfoutput query="qryData">
            <cfset startHours = Int(qryData.startTime / 3600)>
            <cfset startMinutes = Int( ( qryData.startTime - (startHours * 3600) ) / 60) >
            <cfset startSeconds = Int( qryData.startTime - (startHours * 3600) - (startMinutes * 60) )><cfset startTime = CreateTime(startHours, startMinutes, startSeconds)>
            <cfset endHours = Int(qryData.endTime / 3600)>
            <cfset endMinutes = Int( ( qryData.endTime - (endHours * 3600) ) / 60) >
            <cfset endSeconds = Int( qryData.endTime - (endHours * 3600) - (endMinutes * 60) )>
            <cfset endTime = CreateTime(endHours, endMinutes, endSeconds)>
            <cfset newElement=newElement & chr(10)>
            <cfset newElement = newElement & TimeFormat(startTime, 'HH:MM:SS')&'.000 -->'&TimeFormat(endTime, 'HH:MM:SS')&'.000' & chr(10)>
            <cfset newElement = newElement & XMLFormat('- ' & qryData.caption)&chr(10)></cfoutput><cfcontent type = "text/vtt></cfsilent>    
   <cfoutput>#newElement#</cfoutput>
```

Output :

WEBVTT

00:00:05.000 --> 00:00:10.000

caption 1

00:00:12.000 --> 00:00:20.000

caption 2

00:00:25.000 --> 00:00:30.000

caption 3

firefox generating this format but not displaying while video playing.

Answer (score 0):

Your WebVTT might not be valid. You can validate it here: https://quuz.org/webvtt/

The format should look like:

```
WEBVTT

00:00:05.000 --> 00:00:10.000
caption 1

00:00:12.000 --> 00:00:20.000
caption 2

00:00:25.000 --> 00:00:30.000
caption 3
```

If it is valid post your videojs embed code so we can see what options you are including with the track tag.

Comment: <video id="player1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"  
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>  
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<track kind="subtitles" src="/cc/caption.cfm?method=foo&random=#createUUID()#&ID=#ID#" srclang="en" label="English"></track>
</video>

Comment: I'm able to generate vtt file like you mentioned in comment.Also able to view in chrome. Only issue is with firefox